# Cannot Undo Affect of Exclude Module in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, libraries

I was playing around with a library I made that uses Eventbus. First I included the library like so in my app:

```
implementation project(':mylib')
```

and I was able to use Eventbus in the app no problem.
Then I tried the following in the same file just to mess around:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation (project(':mylib')){
    exclude module 'eventbus'
}
```

and as expected I was able to still use Eventbus, but now I have reverted back to

```
implementation project(':mylib')
```

And I can no longer access Eventbus in my app. I tried cleaning from Android Studio, from the command line, I have tried rebuilding, making, invalidating and restarting, no matter what I still get an unresolved reference to greenrobot, Eventbus, etc.

I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out what exactly this changed and I can't find anything on how to "undo" a module exclusion. How can I resolve this?

**Edit:**

I should clarify that I can compile just fine by adding `implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'` back into the gradle file. I was just curious why the other way was working and now is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete folders:

```
/.idea
/.gradle
build
```